# grade sync failed when i want to import a project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i want to import a project in to android studio but i have an error gradle sync failed .

this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle sync failed: Cause: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

i changed the distributionUrl but doesn't solve the problem .

[image]

my gradle-wrapper propertice:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

i searched the net for 3-4 hours but there was no solution for my problem that can solve my problem .

Answer (score 2):

Hope it works
File → Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run.

Comment: instant run can't be unchecked . it's disable to uncheck it

Comment: Whatis your Android Studio Version?

Comment: android studio 2.3.3

Comment: Restart you android studio and check again

Comment: Gradle version?  Change build.gradle in project

Change

dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' }

And also I change the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties(Global Version) distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip